# Jquery Ajax with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am making an ajax query from spring mvc JSP page.The request is made and I am able to see the json response on the browser.

```
$.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/xxx.htm", {x: y}, function(result){

        $.each(result.objects, function( index, object) {
             $(":checkbox[value="+object.id+"]").attr("checked","true");
             $( "#z" ).append(object.name+" ");
        });
    });
```

But, I am not getting the data in the above code. Even though the console display the json data, it also shows the error as below.

```
jquery.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

at Function.each (jquery.js:12)

at Object.success
```

But when I copied the json data from browser and used it as a source, I am able to do the $.each(). But duting $.get(), it displays the above error.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: add output for console.log(result) BEFORE $.each

Answer (score 0):

Unless your server response is setting the content to `application/json` jQuery will not convert it to an object in your success callback. So you have to set the content type specifically in the get request

```
$.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/xxx.htm", {x: y}, function(result){

        $.each(result.objects, function( index, object) {
             $(":checkbox[value="+object.id+"]").attr("checked","true");
             $( "#z" ).append(object.name+" ");
        });

}, 'json');
```